# NextJS render Link with createElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to render a Link with createElement in NextJS, but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
import {createElement} from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
createElement(
    item.href ? Link : "div",
    {
        href: item.href
    }, <button>{item.title}</button>
)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link is defined as follows in `node_modules/next/dist/client/link.d.ts`

```
/// <reference types="node" />
import React from 'react';
import { UrlObject } from 'url';
declare type Url = string | UrlObject;
export declare type LinkProps = {
    href: Url;
    as?: Url;
    replace?: boolean;
    scroll?: boolean;
    shallow?: boolean;
    passHref?: boolean;
    prefetch?: boolean;
    locale?: string | false;
};
declare function Link(props: React.PropsWithChildren<LinkProps>): React.DetailedReactHTMLElement<{
    onMouseEnter?: ((event: React.MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined;
    onClick: (event: React.MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>) => void;
    href?: string | undefined;
    ref?: any;
}, HTMLElement>;
export default Link;
```

You would have to import `LinkProps` or define that type yourself

Property `href` is of type `Url` which is defined as

```
declare type Url = string | UrlObject
```

Where `UrlObject` is defined as

```
    interface UrlObject {
        auth?: string | null;
        hash?: string | null;
        host?: string | null;
        hostname?: string | null;
        href?: string | null;
        pathname?: string | null;
        protocol?: string | null;
        search?: string | null;
        slashes?: boolean | null;
        port?: string | number | null;
        query?: string | null | ParsedUrlQueryInput;
    }
```

Where `ParsedUrlQueryInput` is

```
interface ParsedUrlQueryInput extends NodeJS.Dict<string | number | boolean | ReadonlyArray<string> | ReadonlyArray<number> | ReadonlyArray<boolean> | null> {}
```

This is the input value of `interface ParsedUrlQuery`, which you get in next using router.query/context.query or context.params (in getStaticProps). `ParsedUrlQuery` is a Dictionary type:

```
interface ParsedUrlQuery extends NodeJS.Dict<string | string[]> { }
```

The only way this will work is if you get `LinkProps` or define them yourself, then, you have to use `React.forwardRef` and merge the refs of a custom Component injected with `Link`s properties...alternatively, you could try using

```
let linkType: typeof Link
```

What is your use case for wanting to achieve this though? I'm asking because I'm confused as to why you'd want a custom Link as opposed to a custom anchor component that accepts the `passHref` value from `Link` in the virtual DOM if the anchor tag is wrapping a react functional component. The reason I ask is because I came across an issue where I was trying to wrap a functional component with data (cards) as follows:

```
<>
    <Link
        passHref
        href={`/services/[slug]`}
        as={`/services/${encodeURIComponent(
            popservice.node.slug
        )}`}
        scroll={true}
    >
        <a className='block' key={i++}>
            <ServiceTopTemplate service={popservice.node} />
        </a>
    </Link>
</>
```

This wasn't behaving flawlessly, and after some digging, I found that if you wrap a Functional Component such as `ServiceTopTemplate` with `Link->a->FC`, you need to have an anchor component with a [forwardedRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) for the route to be properly embedded in the anchor. So, I resolved this issue by making an agnostic, reusable, Anchor component with a forwardedRef

```
<>
    <Link
        passHref
        href={`/services/[slug]`}
        as={`/services/${encodeURIComponent(
            popservice.node.slug
        )}`}
        scroll={true}
    >
        <Anchor className='block' key={i++}>
            <ServiceTopTemplate service={popservice.node} />
        </Anchor>
    </Link>
</>
```

The custom `Anchor` component is defined as follows:

```
import mergeRefs from 'react-merge-refs';
import { LoadingSpinner } from '@/components/UI';
import cn from 'classnames';
import css from './anchor.module.css';
import React, {
    FC,
    CSSProperties,
    AnchorHTMLAttributes,
    useRef,
    JSXElementConstructor
} from 'react';
import { Url } from 'url';

// Omit intrinsic href to reinject with conditional Url interface to accept query hrefs from next/link
// query hrefs, e.g.: href={{ query: { slug }, pathname: '', href: '', { ...options, etc } }}

export interface ForwardedAnchorProps<T = HTMLAnchorElement>
    extends Omit<AnchorHTMLAttributes<T>, 'href'> {
    className?: string;
    Component?: string | JSXElementConstructor<any>;
    width?: string | number;
    variant?: 'flat' | 'slim';
    loading?: boolean;
    type?: 'submit' | 'link' | 'active';
    href?: string | Url;
    active?: boolean;
    disabled?: boolean;
    style?: CSSProperties | {};
}

// this component serves to wrap imported functional components -- allows for proper embedding of href in browser when
// wrapping functional components with Link and anchor, respectively

const Anchor: FC<ForwardedAnchorProps<HTMLAnchorElement>> =
    React.forwardRef((props, aRef) => {
        const {
            onClick,
            width,
            className,
            href,
            active,
            style,
            variant = 'flat',
            disabled = false,
            loading = false,
            Component = 'a',
            children,
            ...rest
        } = props;

        const ref = useRef<typeof Component>(null);

        const rootClassName = cn(
            css.root,
            {
                [css.slim]: variant === 'slim',
                [css.loading]: loading,
                [css.disabled]: disabled
            },
            className
        );

        return (
            <Component
                aria-pressed={active}
                disabled={disabled}
                ref={mergeRefs([ref, aRef])}
                className={rootClassName}
                onClick={onClick}
                href={href}
                style={{ width, ...style }}
                {...rest}
            >
                {children}
                {loading && (
                    <i className='pl-2 m-0 flex'>
                        <LoadingSpinner className='transform-gpu transition-all duration-150 animate-spin' />
                    </i>
                )}
            </Component>
        );
    });
export default Anchor;
```

The contents of the corresponding css file:

```css
.root {
    @apply cursor-pointer block transition-all ease-in-out duration-150 transform-gpu;
}

.root:hover {
    @apply bg-redditBG;
}

.root:focus {
    @apply outline-none;
}

.root[data-active] {
    @apply hover:bg-redditBG;
}

.loading {
    @apply bg-current text-olive-300 border-redditBG cursor-not-allowed;
}

.slim {
    @apply py-2 transform-none normal-case;
}

.disabled,
.disabled:hover {
    @apply text-olive-400 border-redditBG bg-current bg-opacity-90 cursor-not-allowed;
    filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

UPDATE -- After reexamining your code, try changing this code:

```
<button>{item.title}</button>
```

to this:

```
<a><button>{item.title}</button></a>
```

Then it might work